# MySQL big Hexadecimal Indexes

Tags: mysql

[SOLVED]

For the first time I came across a database with a considerable growth (**125.000 inserts/day**).

This database is used to keep track of equipments of a Network.

I have many data related to those equipments and I'll be updating them day2day (checking if they were upgraded/downgraded/changed position/got unninstalled and thousands of stuff) SO means that I need to constantly Update them and the only fixed thing Would be their serialnumbers.

Now my headache begins...

I have a useless **ID [int(11) PK)**, It's useless because everything I do is based on **SerialNumbers [varchar(22) UQ]**.

Looking further I saw that serialnumbers are always HEX from (7 to 24) places, first thing in my mind was: TADA solved, just put those serialnumbers as integer and work everytime with hex2dec conversions nothing fancy... Then I figured out that unsigned bigints wasn't enough for numbers larger than HEX(16).

And finally, the question:

> Anyone have any idea about which is the fastest indexable way to store
>   my SerialNumber fields?

I don't mind if you didn't try the solution you're about to say, any idea would be welcome and Upvoted :)

The picture below shows a count of serialnumbers for each SerialNumber lenght I have in the database.
[image]

Comment: Maybe this question at DBA SE helps http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/35821/33821

Comment: @OlafDietsche I don't see how it could fit in my scenario :S

Comment: The OP also looks for indexing a `varchar` column. Since you have the same and try to reduce it to a smaller value, the 3. suggestion using some sort of hash value, might be worth considering.

Comment: Hmm I see the point, Ok'll give a try, the problem will be that I'll need to keep storing the SerialNumber as it is in some recoverable way I mean to show in GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check timing. Indexing on such a short char is not much slower than indexing 64-bit ints. Put your serial as PK. For other solutions, you can use 64-bit hash or serial (beware collisions!), or split long serials into 2 parts and make composite PK on two columns which, I think, will be slower than simple index on Serial.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try it! Which kind of field you think would fit better for speed? Varchar(24) or padded Char(24)? Or which?

Comment: Man, really stressed the database and brain here. The best results I've got was using simple varchar primary key as you say (using analyze/optimize after every commit).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best way, but at least is enough for this case:

Using serialnumber as VARCHAR(25) PK (414 seconds for 10.000.000.000 selects)
Using serialnumber as CHAR(25) PK with LPAD (401 seconds for 10.000.000.000 selects)

After simply using ANALYZE TABLE and OPTIMIZE TABLE after every commit, I went to the winner:
**Using serialnumber as VARCHAR(25) PK (268.759 seconds for 10.000.000.000 selects)**

BTW, also discovered that using small updates in my table was faster than using only one, because of this:
[Currently one SQL statement runs from start to end in the same 
physical thread.](http://lists.mysql.com/internals/37329)

[image]